# Modify .bst file to remove comma after volume page

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, aastex, bst

I am using a slightly edited [aasjournal.bst](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/aastex/aasjournal.bst) file, which I have to use for some reason, e.g., to output the bibliography on a "single line". As it is, the style seems to output a comma after the journal page in the bibliography:

```
[1] John, P., & Smith, F. K. 1979, ApJ, 234, 296, [2] ...
```

If I try to edit the `bst` file (for which I have not much experience for), I can remove the comma at the section:

```
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ } % I can remove this comma here
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
```

But then the output does not only remove the last comma, but also that after the journal name:

```
[1] John, P., & Smith, F. K. 1979, ApJ234, 296 [2] ...
```

How can I get an output like the following?

```
    [1] John, P., & Smith, F. K. 1979, ApJ, 234, 296 [2] ...
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "slightly edited" .bst -- do you mean the one change noted or some additional changes not shown?  Also, please include a minimum working example.

Comment: Thanks John. As far as you know, is this behavior (i.e., removing the indicated comma in the bst file causing the comma to be removed after the journal in the bibliography as well) expected?

Comment: The behavior really depends on how you modify the bst file, since the bst uses a number of different and interlocking functions. You have changed an output function that will affect a number of features, rather than specific features of the article formatting. It's hard to diagnose without knowing what .tex code is used and what other changes may have been made to the bst.

Comment: In other words, assuming I have not changed the `bst` file at all, if now I change the `comma` like I showed in the post, what does one expect as output in the bibliography?

Comment: The result also depends on the options you provide to natbib and on what kind of bib entries you have. The default mode of this .bst is not to output on a single line - how have you produced that effect? MWE would help.